# Django REST serializer.is_valid() returns False

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to handle creator field in my view

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def api_create_news_post_view(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    news_post = NewsPost(creator=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = NewsPostSerializer(news_post, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I complement request with needed data and pass it to serializer

```
class NewsPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsPost
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'date_created', 'creator']
```

For this model

```
class NewsPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("News Post")
        verbose_name_plural = ("News Posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("NewsPost_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

I send `"title": "Lansino dores amores devacia ", "content": "Apollo  antro"`
and in my view I get user object from database, create NewsPost based on it and pass it to NewsPostSerializer along with request data, but it doesn't pass validation and returns `"creator": ["This field is required."]`
Can't figure out why it behaves like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It behaves like that because you added `creator` to fields so it's a required field. You  have three solutions to solve your problem, depending on what you want.

Make it an optional field, so you will be able to update `creator` using your API.

```
class NewsPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = NewsPost
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'date_created', 'creator']
```

Make if a read-only field, so you can never write to it (even if you pass it in your PUT payload) but it will be returned with each serialization.

```
class NewsPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsPost
        read_only_fields = ['creator']
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'date_created', 'creator']
```

The third option is to create a serializer without the `creator` field.